# Why can't I add a literal value to an iterator in using the erase() in multimaps c++?

Tags: c++, search, iterator, maps, erase

```
 std::multimap<std::string, std::string> authors;
 authors.insert ({{"Steven,King", "Cujo"}, {"Jesse,James", "The Highlight"}});
 auto it = authors.begin();
 auto retVal2 = authors.erase(it+1);
 for (auto &i : authors){
     std::cout << i.first << " " << i.second << std::endl;
 }
```

Is it not allowed to add values to the iterator to move to the desired location in the multimap?
In vectors this can be done.
Please clarify if there is anyway about this?
thank you.

Comment: A vector iterator is random access but a multimap iterator is only bidirectional. You can use [std::advance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) to adjust it by a value.

Comment: thanks. can you move backwards in a similar way

Comment: @HannuHell -- concerning moving backwards, **read** the text at the link in that comment.

Answer (score 4):

`std::multimap::iterator` is a bidirectional iterator. A bidirectional iterator does not have `operator+` because it can only advance one at a time making `operator+` a very slow function. Maybe you're comparing it to the iterator of something like `std::vector` or `std::array`. However, those are random access iterators where `operator+` can work in constant time.

Since you only need to add `it` by `1`, you can easily replace `it+1` with `std::next(it)`. If you want to make a new iterator `n` elements after `it` you can also do `std::next(it, n)`. Like [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next), there's also [`std::prev`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) for going backwards. If you want to modify `it` itself, you can use `operator++`/`operator--` (which act like how you would expect them to) or use [`std::advance(it, n)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) to go `n` elements forward or backward (There's no opposite of `std::advance` like `std::recede`, to make your iterator go back `n` should be a negative number).

Comment: Bidirectional iterators also support `++` and `--`.

Comment: @PeteBecker you're right, forgot to mention that. Added to the answer.